# JavaScript alert: quero que saia somente 1 alert esta saindo ate 2 por resposta

Tags: javascript

Quero resolver essa questão, estou iniciando agora, agradeço desde já quem ajudar

```
let idade = parseInt(prompt("digite sua idade? "))
if (idade >= 18 <60){
    alert("voce pode beber");
}
else if (idade <= 18 <60)
    alert("voce Não pode beber");
else (idade >= 60)
    alert("beba com moderação");
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tenta dessa forma aqui:

```js
let idade = parseInt(prompt("digite sua idade? "))

if (idade >= 18 && idade < 60){ 
    alert("voce pode beber"); 
}else if (idade <= 18 ) {
    alert("voce Não pode beber");
}else  {
    alert("beba com moderação");
}
```

Depois dá uma pesquisada nos operadores `||` ou `&&`.
Lembrando que no `else` não precisava passar nenhuma instrução com os operadores.

Comment: muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente!